# Problem with creating an ethers adapter through @safe-global/protocol-kit

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a problem with creating an ethers adapter with @safe-global/protocol-kit library.
Here is my code:

```js
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { EthersAdapter } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit';

const RPC_URL = 'https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc';
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);

// Initialize signers
export const owner1Signer = new ethers.Wallet('XXXXXXXXXX', provider);
// const owner2Signer = new ethers.Wallet('YYYYYYYYYY', provider);

export const ethAdapterOwner1 = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider: owner1Signer
});
```

And when i try to run this code with `ts-node initialize.ts`, i get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@safe-global/protocol-kit/contracts/config'
Require stack:
- /home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/contractManager.js
- /home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/index.js
- /home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/initialize.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/home/msolovyev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/src/managers/contractManager.ts:6:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/home/msolovyev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/contractManager.js',
    '/home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/index.js',
    '/home/msolovyev/www/crypto/safe-test-second/initialize.ts'
  ]
}
```

But! At the same time, all modules are installed.
Here is my package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "safe-test-second",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^0.1.0",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "5.7.2"
  }
}
```

Also, if click on `import { EthersAdapter } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit';`
and then on `import { getCompatibilityFallbackHandlerContract, getCreateCallContract, getMultiSendCallOnlyContract, getMultiSendContract, getProxyFactoryContract, getSafeContract, getSignMessageLibContract } from './contracts/safeDeploymentContracts';`
i see this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you test using:

- `protocol-kit` `v0.1.1`
- `api-kit` `1.0.1`
- `safe-core-sdk-types` `v1.10.1`

Comment: Wow o_0. Looks like its working now!!! Great job!